# What are the differences between the two ways to implement Array.prototype.map

Tags: javascript

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function (cb, thisArg) {
    const newArr = []
    for (let i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            newArr[i] = cb.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this)
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
```

```
Array.prototype.myMap = function (cb, thisArg) {
    const newArr = []
    const len = this.length
    for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (i in this) {
            newArr[i] = cb.call(thisArg, this[i], i, this)
        }
    }
    return newArr
}
```

whth the **"i < this.length"** I don't know why isn't pass any test case ,It's show infinite always

Comment: ran your code, `this.length` is never infinite - please show code that fails

Comment: What context are you executing this in, those two pieces of code should be functionally equivalent.

Comment: Reply to above,here's a question from a site called BFE,to avoid suspicion of advertising, I won't post the link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These will be different if the callback function modifies the length of the array being iterated over. For instance:

```
[1, 2, 3].myMap((el, index, array) => {
    array.push(0);
    return el + 1;
});
```

The second version will never end because `this.length` keeps increasing as the loop continues. But the first version just processes the original 3 elements of the array.

Comment: Your answer has opened my eyes, thank you very much